# two aggregate roots in fluent nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many, aggregateroot, mappings

### The problem is that I have two aggregate roots

The Aggregate roots are

1. Project.
2. NewsArticle.

A Project can have a collection of related NewsArticle.
A NewsArticle can have a collection of related Projects.

---

### The requirements are that:

1. A user can assoicate a number of NewsArticle from Projects.
2. A user can assoicate a number of Project from NewsArticles.

---

### In the database.

NewsArticle --* NewsArticleProject *-- Project.

---

### In the mappings

NewsArticle side

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<NewsArticle> mapping)
{
mapping.HasManyToMany(c => c.FeaturedProjects).Cascade.All().Table("NewsArticleProject").AsSet();
}
```

project side

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<Project> mapping)
{
mapping.HasManyToMany(c => c.FeaturedNewsArticles).Table("NewsArticleProject").Inverse().AsSet();
}
```

I also tried `HasMany()` but that gives me an error message complaining about the ColumnName which I also set.

---

I am struggling to get fluent nHibernate to play nicely into the mappings it so that it can for fulfil my requirements.

I can manage to get it to work for one side only but when I try to get it to work with the other side I get this error message.

*Can't figure out what the other side of the many-to-many property 'FeaturedNewsArticles' should be.*

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try and give responsibility for saving to both sides by using Inverse() on "NewsArticle" too.

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<NewsArticle> mapping)
{
  mapping.HasManyToMany(c => c.FeaturedProjects).Cascade.All().Table("NewsArticleProject").Inverse().AsSet();
}
```